# How to implement Google Drive and Google Plus sdk in ios project

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-plus

I am a beginner in IOS.
Is there any way to integrate both Google plus and Google drive SDK in ios.

Thanks

Comment: [This page](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/) might also be worth visiting to dig into the Google Drive part of your question...

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, there was a Google Developer Live video on this very thing a while back: https://developers.google.com/live/shows/31119462-12001

Comment: What about changes that needs to be made in order to compile the xcode project? SO is asking for a solution not something descriptive on usage of google plus signin button.

Answer (score 0):

This is late. But, i figured out the way on my own. And i wasted my 4 hours on this. So, posting this may help someone else from wasting hours!!

1. SVN checkout from http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
2. After checkout completes, Go to Source folder and open GTL.xcodeproj.
3. See the image[image]