# How to use GoogleDrive and GooglePlus API in one app in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, google-plus

I am developing an app that [[image]google-drive-sdk](/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk) has been successfully integrated onto, but now I want to share my app on [[image]google-plus](/questions/tagged/google-plus) so I used Google+ SDK, and it conflicts with GoogleDrive SDK.

I used [GTLDriveFile Class](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_drive_file) for GoogleDrive, 
and I followed [these steps for installing GoogleDrive](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart).

It works fine with just GoogleDrive SDK. But if I add Google+ SDK then it'll conflict with GoogleDrive SDK. I've tried lots of time and searched on Google but I can't find anything.

I only found these links:

[1: (SO) How to implement Google Drive and Google Plus sdk in ios project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212166/how-to-implement-google-drive-and-google-plus-sdk-in-ios-project)

[2: (YouTube) Google Drive SDK: using the Google+ Sign-In button with Drive on iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qXMi--qk9Q)

### Update:

It displays `duplicate symbols for architecture i386`

If I delete one file then it will display the same error in another file because in following folder

> GTL->GTL Source->Common->Objects

which has all the files, which are already available in

> GoogleOpenSource.framework

And if I deleted all the `.h` files from the GTL folder then it won't work either, it gives a 'file not found' error.

Can anyone help me?

### Update

If I had not added `GoogleOpenSource.framework` but I added only `GooglePlus.framework` then it gives me error like....

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not provided any details about what conflict you are having.

Comment: Someone wants to close this question, what is wrong with this question? can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to drop the GoogleOpenSource.framework - that just includes the Plus relevant parts of GTL and GTM which you're likely to be bringing in as part of the Drive client library. If you need any files from it, you can find the source version of whats included within the original SDK zip you downloaded.

To be clear:

1. Delete GoogleOpenSource.framework from your projectList item
2. If there are any errors on missing files, bring those in individually from the open source folder in the Google+ SDK zip. Include both the .m and .h files

Comment: What is it conflicting with if you don't have GoogleOpenSource.framework in there? I've updated the answer with some clearer steps.

Comment: Have you added the .h and .m files? To be absolutely clear: Within the Google+ SDK zip there are two copies of the open source parts - one in a framework, one not. You want the one *not* in a framework. Then you can just bring in the non-clashing parts.

Comment: @MilanMendpara can you describe what you done, which step you followed?

Answer (score 0):

It's much more simpler than @Ian's answer. No offence @Ian. :)

1. SVN checkout from http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
2. After checkout completes, Go to Source folder and open GTL.xcodeproj.
3. See the image[image]